# Python adding self to start using registry

Tags: python, registry

I am trying to get my python file to add itself to start using the registry. I know i can just put it in the file myself but i want to be able to do it automatically when the file runs.

My current code:

```
def addtoStart():

try:

    filePath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)


    winreg.SetValueEx(reg_key, "Name", 0, winreg.REG_SZ,
    filePath)

    winreg.CloseKey()
except:
    pass
```

I have converted my python file to an exe and run it as administrator but still it doesnt work. Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "doesn't work" mean?